# Valid JSON not working with jQuery.parseJSON()

Tags: php, javascript, json

I'm saving a JSON string to a file and trying to read it back. For some reason it won't read it back. jsonlint.com is telling me it is a valid JSON.

Here is the JSON string:

```
{"userdef":{"vlan10":{"dfault":{"down":{"rate":"876","ceil":"876"},"up":{"rate":"876","ceil":"876"}},"upsell":{"down":{"rate":"876","ceil":"876"},"up":{"rate":"876","ceil":"76"}}},"br0":{"dfault":{"down":{"rate":"798","ceil":"987"},"up":{"rate":"987","ceil":"987"}},"upsell":{"down":{"rate":"98","ceil":"987"},"up":{"rate":"987","ceil":"89"}}},"br1":{"dfault":{"down":{"rate":"3","ceil":"654"},"up":{"rate":"654","ceil":"63"}},"upsell":{"down":{"rate":"65","ceil":"4"},"up":{"rate":"646","ceil":"5"}}},"eth3":{"dfault":{"down":{"rate":"65","ceil":"7876"},"up":{"rate":"7657","ceil":"5"}},"upsell":{"down":{"rate":"7865","ceil":"7"},"up":{"rate":"7","ceil":"5"}}}}}
```

Here is javascript/php code:

```
<?
if (file_exists('/tmp/qosconfig.conf'))
{
?>
var config = jQuery.parseJSON('<?=file_get_contents("/tmp/qosconfig.conf");?>');    
<?
}
?>
```

Comment: That works for me.  Read the generated source.

Comment: could /tmp/qosconfig.conf have some extra whitespace or a BOM that might be screwing things up?

Comment: I'd attempt using `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` rather than relying on jQuery to do that.

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica `$.parseJSON` merely wraps `JSON.parse` if available, and uses a workaround if not.

Comment: you combine JS and PHP - `if (file_exists('/tmp/qosconfig.conf')) echo "var config = jQuery.parseJSON('" + file_get_contents('/tmp/qosconfig.conf')" + "');";`

Comment: `var config = <?=file_get_contents("/tmp/qosconfig.conf");?>);` should suffice, but there must be some other problem too

Comment: I had the same thought... why do you need to parse it as a string ? The JSON string you put is already a plain & valid JSON expression.

Comment: When I use JSON.parse() this is what the js log shows: config.toString()
"[object Object]"
console.log(config)
undefined
When I use jQuery.parseJSON() I get this: 
config.toString()
"[object Object]"
console.log(config)
undefined

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather odd way of doing this.  If you have the JSON string available to you in PHP, you can output it into the javascript as an object literal which saves the parsing step.

```
<?
if (file_exists('/tmp/qosconfig.conf')) {
    $json = file_get_contents('/tmp/qosconfig.conf');
?>
var config = <?php echo $json; ?>;    
<?
}
?>
```